# Loteria, ejercicio sobre Loteria

Tags: java

Estoy liado haciendo un pequeño programa que calcule una Lotería.

Me explico, esto lo estoy desarrollando en java.

Tenemos una clase *apuestas* con un `ArrayList` de apuestas. Tenemos una clase apuesta, donde tenemos un bombo de números aleatorios que van de 1 hasta 49, y donde tengo distintos métodos. Entre ellos hay uno donde genero las apuestas aleatorias y donde compruebo que haya acertados. Luego hay un método *Main* donde hago las llamadas y hago las salidas oportunas. Mi duda es que no sé cémo comparar el contenido de los arrays, y ni si mis métodos son correctos, porque consigo que me muestren las apuestas pero no los acertados. Estos son un array de 6 elementos o yo lo había pensado así, aunque me conformo con que me devuelva si un elemento del array del sorteo está en mi array de la apuesta. os dejo mis clases y todo el código a ver si me lucubrarais un poco.

PD: sé que es un ejercicio simple, pero estoy empezando con programación, y cosas simples como esto me cuestan mucho más que generar una aplicación con GUI que gestione una base de datos por ejemplo...

Gracias de ante mano.

CÓDIGO:

**CLASE APUESTA:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;


public class Apuesta {

    int[] numeros = new int[6];
    int nAciertos;
    ArrayList<Integer> bombo = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public Apuesta(){
        generaApuesta();
    }

    public void generaApuesta(){

        for(int i=0; i<=49;i++){
            bombo.add(i);
        }
       /*Llenamos el array de apuestas*/
       int indice;
       for(int i=1;i<numeros.length;i++){
           indice = (int)(Math.random()*(48-i));
           numeros[i] = bombo.get(indice);
       }
    }

    public int[] getNumeros(){
        return numeros;
    }

    public int[] ordenar(){
        int[] ordenados = new int[6];
        Arrays.sort(numeros);

        for(int i=0; i<numeros.length;i++){
            for(int j=0; j<bombo.size();j++){
                if(i<j){
                    ordenados[i] = i;
                    nAciertos++;
                }else{
                    ordenados[j] = j;
                    nAciertos++;
                }
            }
        }
    return ordenados;
    }

    public int acertados(int[] sorteo){
        for(int i=0; i<sorteo.length;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<numeros.length;j++){
                if(sorteo[i] == numeros[j]){
                    nAciertos++;
                }
            }
        }
    return nAciertos;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return Arrays.toString(numeros) + "\n"+ acertados(getNumeros()); 
    }
}
```

**CLASE APUESTAS:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Apuestas {
    ArrayList<Apuesta> apuestas = new ArrayList<Apuesta>();
    Apuesta apuesta;


public void insertarApuesta(Apuesta a){
    apuestas.add(a);
}


@Override
public String toString(){
    String salida = "";
    for(int i=0; i<apuestas.size();i++){
        salida += i;
    }
return  apuestas.toString() + "\n";
}

}
```

**MAIN**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;

import java.util.Random;


public class Loteria {



public static void main(String[] args) {
    Apuestas apuestas = new Apuestas();

    Apuesta apuesta = null;

    for(int i=0;i<=10;i++){
       apuesta = new Apuesta();
       apuesta.generaApuesta();
       apuestas.insertarApuesta(apuesta);
       apuesta.ordenar();
    }




    Apuesta sorteo = new Apuesta();
    System.out.println("Las apuestas son: " + apuestas.toString());
    sorteo.getNumeros();
    int acertados = apuesta.acertados(sorteo.getNumeros());

    System.out.println("Los numeros acertados son: " + acertados);        
}

}
```

Comment: No se si te servira pero solo estas comparando los aciertos de la ultima apuesta.

Comment: y como puedo comparar de cada apuesta???

Comment: Recorriendo el ArrayList de Apuestas. El cual aparte tiene un objeto de Apuesta que no se usa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He estado revisando tu código y tenías algunos errores para lo que querías hacer: creo que este sería el resultado de lo que esperas:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;

import java.util.Random;

class Apuesta {

    int[] numeros = new int[6];
    int nAciertos;
    ArrayList<Integer> bombo = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public Apuesta(){
        generaApuesta();
    }

    public void generaApuesta(){

        for(int i=0; i<=49;i++){
            bombo.add(i);
        }
        /*Llenamos el array de apuestas*/
        int indice;
        for(int i=0;i<numeros.length;i++){
           indice = (int)(Math.random()*(bombo.size()-i));
           numeros[i] = bombo.remove(indice);
        }
    }

    public int[] getNumeros(){
        return numeros;
    }

    public int[] ordenar(){
        int[] ordenados = new int[6];
        Arrays.sort(numeros);

        for(int i=0; i<numeros.length;i++){
            for(int j=0; j<bombo.size();j++){
                if(i<j){
                    ordenados[i] = i;
                }else{
                    ordenados[j] = j;
                }
            }
        }
        return ordenados;
    }

    public int acertados(int[] sorteo){
        for(int i=0; i<sorteo.length;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<numeros.length;j++){
                if(sorteo[i] == numeros[j]){
                    nAciertos++;
                }
            }
        }
        return nAciertos;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return Arrays.toString(numeros); 
    }
}

class Apuestas {
    ArrayList<Apuesta> apuestas = new ArrayList<Apuesta>();
    Apuesta apuesta;


    public void insertarApuesta(Apuesta a){
        apuestas.add(a);
    }


    @Override
    public String toString(){
        String salida = "";
        for(int i=0; i<apuestas.size();i++){
            salida += i;
        }
    return  apuestas.toString() + "\n";
    }

}

class Loteria {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Apuestas apuestas = new Apuestas();

        Apuesta apuesta = null;

        Apuesta sorteo = new Apuesta();

        System.out.println("Apuestas realizadas para el sorteo: "+sorteo);
        for(int i=0;i<=10;i++){
           apuesta = new Apuesta();
           apuesta.generaApuesta();
           apuestas.insertarApuesta(apuesta);
           apuesta.ordenar();

            int acertados = apuesta.acertados(sorteo.getNumeros());

            System.out.println("\t"+apuesta+" Acertó " + acertados+" números");        

        }
    }
}
```

Produce esta salida de ejemplo

```
Apuestas realizadas para el sorteo: [44, 34, 18, 15, 25, 39]
    [3, 9, 10, 19, 39, 39] Acertó 2 números
    [20, 27, 34, 43, 45, 47] Acertó 1 números
    [0, 13, 34, 36, 44, 46] Acertó 2 números
    [1, 16, 16, 17, 30, 39] Acertó 1 números
    [11, 13, 15, 21, 23, 37] Acertó 1 números
    [3, 16, 20, 23, 26, 35] Acertó 0 números
    [4, 4, 6, 8, 34, 49] Acertó 1 números
    [0, 19, 24, 27, 35, 38] Acertó 0 números
    [3, 24, 27, 30, 42, 49] Acertó 0 números
    [13, 19, 21, 38, 43, 46] Acertó 0 números
    [9, 14, 32, 34, 34, 47] Acertó 2 números
```

Comment: Mil gracias compañero, que maravilla de comunidad.

Answer (score 0):

No sé exactamente lo que quiere hacer alguna parte del código. Te indico mediante comentarios los cambios que introduciría y las dudas que me surgen:

CLASE APUESTA:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;


public class Apuesta {

    int[] numeros = new int[6];
    int nAciertos;

/* Creo que sobraría, simplemente tienes una lista que sabes que
es de 49 números (esto podrías definirlo como una constante)
en la que la posición i tiene valor i */
    ArrayList<Integer> bombo = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public Apuesta(){
        generaApuesta();
    }

    public void generaApuesta(){

        for(int i=0; i<=49;i++){
            bombo.add(i);
        }
       /*Llenamos el array de apuestas*/
       int indice;
       for(int i=1;i<numeros.length;i++){

/*No entiendo el 48-i. No te asegura que no haya repetidos si es eso lo que
quieres, lo único que consigue es que el segundo número sea menor que 48,
el tercero menor que 47...*/
           indice = (int)(Math.random()*(48-i));

   // ¿En vez de esto, donde igualas el indice arriba, igualar numeros [i]?
           numeros[i] = bombo.get(indice);
       }
    }

    public int[] getNumeros(){
        return numeros;
    }

    public int[] ordenar(){

/* No entiendo nada del método. Con el .sort, suficiente.
¿El resto para qué es? ¿Y lo de incrementar el número de aciertos?
¿No hay un método que se encarga de eso ya? */

  int[] ordenados = new int[6];
        Arrays.sort(numeros);

        for(int i=0; i<numeros.length;i++){
            for(int j=0; j<bombo.size();j++){
                if(i<j){
                    ordenados[i] = i;
                    nAciertos++;
                }else{
                    ordenados[j] = j;
                    nAciertos++;
                }
            }
        }
    return ordenados;
    }

    public int acertados(int[] sorteo){
        for(int i=0; i<sorteo.length;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<numeros.length;j++){
                if(sorteo[i] == numeros[j]){
                    nAciertos++;
// Se va a ganar muy poca eficiencia, pero un break aquí sería lo suyo
                }
            }
        }
    return nAciertos;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
/* acertados(getNumeros) va a comparar cuantos hay iguales
entre numeros y numeros, ¿no?*/
        return Arrays.toString(numeros) + "\n"+ acertados(getNumeros()); 
    }
}
```

CLASE APUESTAS:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Apuestas {
    ArrayList<Apuesta> apuestas = new ArrayList<Apuesta>();
    Apuesta apuesta;


public void insertarApuesta(Apuesta a){
    apuestas.add(a);
}


@Override
public String toString(){
    String salida = "";
    for(int i=0; i<apuestas.size();i++){
        salida += i;
    }
return  apuestas.toString() + "\n";
}

}
```

MAIN:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;

import java.util.Random;


public class Loteria {



public static void main(String[] args) {
    Apuestas apuestas = new Apuestas();

    Apuesta apuesta = null;

    for(int i=0;i<=10;i++){
       apuesta = new Apuesta();
       apuesta.generaApuesta();
       apuestas.insertarApuesta(apuesta);
       apuesta.ordenar();
    }




    Apuesta sorteo = new Apuesta();
    System.out.println("Las apuestas son: " + apuestas.toString());
    sorteo.getNumeros();

/* ¿Sería sorteo.acertados(apuesta.getNumeros())?
Estas dos líneas no deberían ser dentro de un for
que recorriese cada apuesta dentro de apuestas?
int acertados = apuesta.acertados(sorteo.getNumeros()); */

    System.out.println("Los numeros acertados son: " + acertados);        
}

}
```

Si algo no te queda claro, o quieres aclararme algo, adelante.

Comment: gracias por intentar ayudarme, ya me han respondido con lo que necesitaba.